# TAB autocomplete does not work on Jupyter Notebook - JEDI uninstall possible?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I know this topic is not new but still I havent found a solution.
The TAB autocomplete/ intellisense for Jupyter notebooks doesnt seem to work properly.

I have tried the following possible fixes from several sources:

downgrade jedi=0.17.2
downgrade parso=0.6.2
install pyreadline

nothing really worked reliably. The only thing which seems to fix this is to add the following line on top of each notebook.

```
%config Completer.use_jedi = False
```

But thats not a proper solution. So I figured maybe uninstall jedi altogether.

So my question is: is JEDI really needed to run Juypter Notebooks properly?

Many thanks in advance

A